# Помогите в использовании QDialog как не модального

Tags: c++, qt

Здесь приведён фрагмент кода для открытия не модального диалогового окна. Вопрос: почему не отобразилось окно?

```
   QPushButton *btnNewWnd = new QPushButton("&Открыть новое окно");
    vbox->addWidget(btnNewWnd);

    QObject::connect(btnNewWnd, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this, SLOT(onBtnPressed()));

}//accept

void ised_win::onBtnPressed()
{
    ndlg = new QDialog(this);
    ndlg->setModal(false);
    QVBoxLayout* l = new QVBoxLayout;
    int c = calc();
    for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j)
    {
        char buffer[3];
        itoa(j, buffer, 10);//to do
        auto bp = new QTextEdit(buffer);
        l->addWidget(bp);
    }
    ndlg->setLayout(l);
    ndlg->show();
}
```

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, но у вас память утекает - `ndlg` не удаляется

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог метод `QDialog::resize`